# How to display the tables one next to the other

Tags: javascript, css, html

#### Code

```js
$(function() {
  var dmJSON = "data.json";

  $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
    $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
      var $table = "<table border=5></br><tbody><tr>"
        + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td></tr>"
        + "<tr><td>" + f.Answer + "</td></tr>"
        + "<tr><td>" + f.Status + "</td></tr>"
        + "<tr><td> " + f.Views + "</td></tr>"
        + "</tbody></table>";

      $("#entrydata").append($table)
    });
  });
});
```

With this code the dynamically created tables are displaying one below the other but I want them to be displayed one next to the other.

How to solve this? Any solution to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `table` are block level elements so to aligned them next to each other you can choose `display:inline-table` or also can choose `float:left` for both tables. And Parents Items must have use `clear fix method` to remove the floating.

Comment: You should use `inline-table` on `table` elements, not `inline-block`.

Comment: i added clear fix method and inline table. But it's still not working

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="profile">
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div id='entrydata'></div>

                    </div>
              </div>

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, simply set your `table` element to `display: inline-table`:

```css
table {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

---

On a side note, `</br>` is not a valid child of `<table>`.